# Require authentication for a folder instead of multiple pages in the folder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm currently trying to add password authentication to two of my pages Page1.aspx, and Page2.aspx which are both located in the "Admin" folder but am not sure what I'm missing to make it work. The code that is in my web.config file is shown below, what am I missing or misplacing in the code?

Clarification: I want to require a login which I have a page called 'Login.aspx' to two pages within one folder and I just want to set the location path to that folder instead of two location paths, one to each page.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode ="Forms">
        <forms timeout = "30">
            <credentials passwordFormat ="MD5">
                <user name ="admin" password ="21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3"/>
            </credentials>
        </forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>

<!-- Require login for Admin Directory -->
<location path ="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users ="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This should work, what is your actual problem? What happens when you request /admin/page1.aspx?

Comment: Does it work when you specify the path as /Admin/Page1.aspx ?

Comment: I'm dumb, I believe that the session was saved to my browser thus not being logged out until another 30 minutes. Thank you for your concern/effort in my problem.

Comment: It's ok. You're welcome :) It's the forms authentication cookie by the way, which is saved to your browser and is sent with each request to the page. You can change the name of that cookie as well in your Forms tag. Cheers